# Can't we initialize and close python multiprocessing pool multiple times?

Tags: python, tuples

It accumulates for the **fileNum=1** bot not for **fileNum=2**

Can't we initialize and close `pool` multiple times?

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def prepare_data_fill_arrays(fileNum,simNum,chrLong):
    arrayList=[]
    array1=np.ones((10,))*simNum*fileNum
    array2=np.ones((10,))*simNum*fileNum
    arrayList.append(simNum)
    arrayList.append(chrLong)
    arrayList.append(array1)
    arrayList.append(array2)
    return arrayList

if __name__ == '__main__':

    numofFiles=2
    numofSimulations = 10
    chromNamesList = ['chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3', 'chr4', 'chr5', 'chr6', 'chr7', 'chrX', 'chr8', 'chr9', 'chr10', 'chr11',
                      'chr12', 'chr13', 'chr14', 'chr15', 'chr16', 'chr17', 'chr18', 'chr20', 'chrY', 'chr19', 'chr22',
                      'chr21', 'chrM']

    sim_nums = range(0, numofSimulations + 1)
    sim_num_chr_tuples = ((sim_num, chrLong) for sim_num in sim_nums for chrLong in chromNamesList)

    files=range(1, numofFiles+1)

    for fileNum in files:
        jobs = []
        accumulatedArray1 = np.zeros((numofSimulations, 10))
        accumulatedArray2 = np.zeros((numofSimulations, 10))

        def accumulateArray(arrayList):
            try:
                simNum = arrayList[0]
                chrLong = arrayList[1]
                array1 = arrayList[2]
                array2 = arrayList[3]
                accumulatedArray1[simNum - 1] += array1
                accumulatedArray2[simNum - 1] += array2
                # print('ACCUMULATION simNum:%d chrLong:%s' % (simNum, chrLong))
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception: %s" % (e))

        numofProcesses = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=numofProcesses)

        for simNum, chrLong in sim_num_chr_tuples:
            jobs.append(pool.apply_async(prepare_data_fill_arrays,
                                 args=(fileNum,simNum,chrLong,),
                                 callback=accumulateArray))
        for job in jobs:
            job.get()

        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print('###################################')
        print('filenum:%d' %(fileNum))
        print("accumulatedArray1:%s" %(accumulatedArray1))
        print("accumulatedArray2:%s" %(accumulatedArray2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing this

```
sim_num_chr_tuples = ((sim_num, chrLong) for sim_num in sim_nums for chrLong in chromNamesList)
```

to, e.g.,

```
sim_num_chr_tuples = [(sim_num, chrLong) for sim_num in sim_nums for chrLong in chromNamesList]
```

That is, you want to iterate over `sim_num_chr_tuples` multiple times, but the original spelling is a generator expression, which is exhausted after the first time you iterate over it.  The second time around,

```
    for simNum, chrLong in sim_num_chr_tuples:
```

finds nothing to do.  Materialize into a list instead, and then you can iterate over it any number of times.

This has nothing to do with multiprocessing, BTW.

Comment: To use less memory I used a generator, so I can prepare a generator each time I enter the for loop for each file.